# Who is my database administrator in a cPanel account?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, cpanel

I'm operating a Wordpress site in an online account running cPanel platform. I was given this site and it works fine, but I've been having some problems with the MySQL database and I don't know who is the database provider. I know the web hosting provider, but I can't identify who is the DB provider.

Everything says cPanel, but I know cPanel is the platform, not the provider per se.

Do you know how can I identify the DB provider?

Many thanks,

Rodrigo

Comment: Ask your colleague or manager instead.

Comment: You can use website like www.whois.com to display the information of a website.

Comment: The webserver and database usually run on the same physical machine, and are both configured by cPanel. The bad news: in these scenarios, you are usually the person WP means when it talks about database administrator, as its problems aren't "We need somebody with super user privileges", but "Somebody has to look at this". You are that somebody.